# Why is the purple becoming a dingy green on my wandering Jew?

Tags: houseplants

[image]

It was getting full direct sunglight out on my porch. I’ve moved it inside and am trying to give it indirect, bright sunlight. If too much direct sun is the reason for this when should I expect it to recover ? Or perhaps it is root bound ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plant is officially called Tradescantia 'zebrina', common names Inch plant or Wandering Jew. This one does need some direct sun, or it will lose its coloration, so bright light most of the time, with some sunlight. Outdoors, they can scorch in full sun, but in the house it's not usually a problem because no plant will receive full sun exposure all day indoors. So a windowsill that's sunny in the morning, afternoon or evening should be fine.

In regard to its being rootbound, there's so much foliage I can't see the size of pot its in, so hard to say. You can turn it out of its pot and have a look - if it is rootbound, chop it in half and pot up the halves separately. https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/wandering-jew-inch-plant

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how long it will approximately take for these changes to revive the color in my plant ?

Comment: Its hard to say - its dependent on how much sun it gets indoors, but you should notice a difference within a month. Even without the purple undersides, yours is a very attractive plant anyway, but do check if its rootbound or not.